# How to force Dapper dot net to use its implementation of IDbCommand.ExecuteReader

Tags: c#, dapper

Background:

I'm in the process of integrating Dapper into an existing application that has a legacy DAL based off of the DAAB of years gone by. This is a fairly large code base so it has to be done incrementally. My first attempt is taking a method that calls a reader and populates a collection of objects.

What I'm noticing is that the query extension method seems to be calling the IDbCommand.ExecuteReader and the legacy DAL implementation is being invoked instead of the Dapper version.

So my question is this "Is there a way to explicitly force Dapper to use it's implementation of IDbCommand.ExecuteReader and not the legacy version?"

Setup Connection: The open connection is coming from the existing framework and it completely wraps the IDbConnection interface plus some. There is a lot of security around getting this connection, and other additions that seem to muddy the waters.

```
private static XyDbConnection GetConnection()
{
    return XyDbConnection.GetConnection(ExternalFieldDataConstants.ConnectionName.SecureRepositoryConnection);
}
```

Callsite: Nothing terrible going on here just setup of Dapper in a typical scenario

```
private void GetFieldMappingTableDapper()
{
    const string commandText = @"
        SELECT
            OD.ObjectDefId,
            OD.Name,
            FM.LOBField,
            FM.XPath, 
            FM.XPathDataType,
            FM.legacyOnly,
            BA.NAME BusinessAreaName
        FROM    [FieldMapping] FM
        JOIN    [ObjectDef] OD 
        ON  OD.ObjectDefId = FM.ObjectDefId
        JOIN    [BusinessArea] BA 
        ON  BA.BusinessAreaId = OD.BusinessAreaId";

    using (var conn = GetConnection())
    {
        _mappingsCache = conn.Query<FieldMappingEx>(commandText).ToList();
    }
}
```

Pictures are worth a thousand words.

Setting up the call to Dapper:
[image]

Now when I step (F11) into the call I get:
[image]

And now the most interesting part is the invocation of the legacy command object from Dapper. (it seems)
[image]

I've used Dapper for years, even with Oracle :) and this is the first time I've ever had a hickup, period.

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: Can you show what code you are calling? also, what is the connection type here? is it possible that the connection provider is doing something crazy here? No: dapper can't call into your existing DAL, so one of: the wrong method is being called in the first place, or the connection is doing something crazy, or what is happening is happening in another place :)

Comment: For example: dapper *doesn't have* an `IDbCommand.ExecuteReader`; it has an `IDbConnection.ExecuteReader` method. If your base object is a command: you're not using dapper in the first place.

Comment: You can't compile if you have ambiguous extension methods, so its not possible that some other method is trumping your intended use of the Dapper extension method, fyi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, dapper calls the `CreateCommand` method on the connection. It has to. It doesn't know anything about what type of connection you are using. That is literally the only way you *should* (as a provider-agnostic library) create a command. Is there a different way you expected it to create an ado.net command?

Comment: No, coding against the interface is what you're supposed to do. I need to either create a more generic connection object without the baggage or separate the legacy DAL and the new DAL so I won't have these issues. Thanks for responding so quickly Marc.

Comment: @Stephen the decorator pattern works quite well in ado.net if you need - so you could have a basic provider that you then wrap in a souped-up provider - just give dapper the basic "tail". See mini-profiler for an example (ProfiledDbConnection)

Comment: How about the Undecorator pattern, that's what I need... I'm just trying to bring this guys up and out of the .NET 2.0 era.